# How to put a space in front of a next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve some this like this in bootstrap or css

```
<div class="col-xs-2">Description</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">: I am a noob</div>
```

I get the following resut:

```
Description    : I am a 
               noob
```

How can I do this?

```
Description    : I am a 
                 noob
```

Comment: There isnt enough code here to provide a definitive answer. Can you post a short self contained example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a pseudo-element to insert the `:` and keep the space of those along the text:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 doublep"><span>I am a noob</span></div>

.doublep {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.doublep:before {
  width: 15px;
  text-align: Center;
  font-size: 14px;
  content: ":";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.doublep span {
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/BokRiDv8sB)**

Answer (score 1):

you can add some      `&nbsp;`  (html space) and you will get what you want.
other wish grab the last word in `<div>` then style the `<div>` to margin left few pixels